# How can I calculate differences (luminosity, brightness, color) between two colors?

Tags: math, colors, brightness

How can I calculate

- the luminosity contrast ratio,
- the difference in brightness, and
- the difference in color

between two given colors?

**Example:**

*Input*

- color 1 : #99ccff
- color 2: #225588

*Output*

- luminosity contrast ratio : 4.57 : 1
- difference in brightness : 119
- difference in color : 357

Comment: I seem to remember something like this ((red_value1 * 299 + green_value1 * 587 + blue_value1 * 114)/(red_value2 * 299 + green_value2 * 587 + blue_value2 * 114))

Comment: @anirudh4444 : For my example, the result is 2.57490315... Doesn't look like any of the expected outputs. What is this supposed to calculate? Any idea where these magic numbers come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert each colour from (R, G, B) to (H, S, V) [or (H, S, L)] coordinates. You can find formulae [at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

I have written Pascal functions for this:

```
function RGBToHSV(const Color: TRGB): THSV;
var
  cmax, cmin, cdiff: real;
begin
  cmax := MaxComponent(Color);
  cmin := MinComponent(Color);
  cdiff := cmax - cmin;

  with Color, result do
  begin

    // Hue
    if cmax = cmin then
      hsvHue := 0
    else if cmax = rgbRed then
      hsvHue := (60 * (rgbGreen - rgbBlue) / cdiff)
    else if cmax = rgbGreen then
      hsvHue := (60 * (rgbBlue - rgbRed) / cdiff) + 120
    else
      hsvHue := (60 * (rgbRed - rgbGreen) / cdiff) + 240;

    hsvHue := Fix360(hsvHue);

    // Saturation
    if cmax = 0 then
      hsvSaturation := 0
    else
      hsvSaturation := 1 - cmin / cmax;

    // Value
    hsvValue := cmax;

  end;

end;

function RGBToHSL(const Color: TRGB): THSL;
var
  cmax, cmin, cdiff, csum: real;
begin
  cmax := MaxComponent(Color);
  cmin := MinComponent(Color);
  cdiff := cmax - cmin;
  csum := cmax + cmin;

  with Color, result do
  begin

    // Hue
    if cmax = cmin then
      hslHue := 0
    else if cmax = rgbRed then
      hslHue := (60 * (rgbGreen - rgbBlue) / cdiff)
    else if cmax = rgbGreen then
      hslHue := (60 * (rgbBlue - rgbRed) / cdiff) + 120
    else
      hslHue := (60 * (rgbRed - rgbGreen) / cdiff) + 240;

    hslHue := Fix360(hslHue);

    // Saturation
    if cmax = cmin then
      hslSaturation := 0
    else if csum <= 1 then
      hslSaturation := cdiff / csum
    else
      hslSaturation := cdiff / (2 - csum);

    // Lightness
    hslLightness := csum / 2;

  end;

end;
```

Comment: I also found thins link (no need to know about Pascal): http://130.113.54.154/~monger/hsl-rgb.html

Comment: @Shawn: Well, Pascal is very readable and very similar to 'pseudo langauges' used in advanced math books when algorithms are described...

Comment: Rajbrand : Yes it's pretty good. I just didn't understand the `with Color, result do` and `Fix360` parts, so I ended up having to look it up elsewhere anyways..